# GridLayoutManager Same Image Sizes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am experimenting with the `RecyclerView` and the `GridLayoutManager`.

I ultimately want to display images that are the same size that appear like this, or even square if possible:

[image]

What is the element of the `GridLayoutManager` to make this possible? Do I modify the individual item XML that I use to populate the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: You can customize your custom row item layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you have to subclass an `ImageView` like below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MyImageview extends ImageView {
    public MyImageview (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyImageview (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyImageview (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); // Snap to
        // width
    }
}
```

**Use this file in XML File.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.app.MyImageview 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure your `MyImageView` height and width must be `match_parent`.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot, but where does the alignment actually come in? All I see you doing is matching parent...not saying you are wrong just want to understand where it constrains each image to a fixed size

Comment: @Dixit Panchal this works great, but Is there's way to use / override onMeasure method without creating this class?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Picaso then user below to make it smooth:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(mUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_animated)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop() // resizing images can really distort the aspect ratio, prevent this
            .into(mImageView)
```